# External Dependencies not working in Nav.svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, sapper

I am trying to load sv-bootstrap-dropdown module in nav.svelte component but I am getting the error `<Dropdown> is not a valid SSR component. You may need to review your build config to ensure that dependencies are compiled, rather than imported as pre-compiled modules`. After that I tried to install that as devDependency but than I was getting the error that `Cannot read property remove of undefined`. This gets generated itself in the server js file under the **sapper** folder

Comment: I haven't had any luck getting this working either - any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with svelte and sapper you to have think about 2 types of rendering : client side  rendering (sveltjs, js) and server side rendering (SSR), it's sapper (nodejs or expressjs), there are a few ways to handle this, but according to the document of dependency you are using :

for SSR you consider to import like this:

```
import {
      Carousel,
      CarouselControl,
      CarouselIndicators,
      CarouselItem,
      CarouselCaption
    } from 'sveltestrap/src';
```

solve it by importing from the `src` folder of the package.